# Этимология слова "слишком"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "слишком"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фасмер уверен, что наречие "слишком" произошло от прилагательного "лишний", и ему пока никто не возразил.

[Происходит от прил. *лишний,* далее от *лихой,* из праслав. *leikso-...](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) - Викисловарь со ссылкой на великого этимолога.

> Происходит от прил. лишний, далее от лихой, из праслав. *leikso-, от
> кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. лихъ «лишенный, печальный,
> злой, плохой, лихой, отважный», ст.-слав. лихъ (др-греч. ἀλλότριος),
> укр. лихи́й «злой, дурной, несчастный», болг. лих, ж. лиха́, ср. р.
> лихо́ «злобный, лихой, своенравный», сербохорв. ли̑х, ли̑хо, словенск.
> lȋh «нечетный, непарный», чешск. líchý «лишний, нечетный, лукавый,
> пустой», польск. lichy «нечётный, плохой, бедный», в.-луж. lichi
> «голый, свободный», н.-луж. lichy «холостой». Первонач. *leikso- от
> *loik-; ср. лек, отлек; родственно греч. λεὶψόθριξ «потерявший волосы», λείψανον «остаток», далее лат. relinquō, -lictus «оставляю»,
> греч. λείπω — то же. Первонач. знач. было «остающийся, превышающий
> меру». Разграничение слов liхъ «злой, дурной» и liхъ «лишний» не имеет
> оснований, вопреки Эндзелину. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;

Итак, *лихой* и *лишний* этимологически однокоренные.

[**ЛИХОЙ**](http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/11/str174.html)

Очень близко к "лишний": ведь "вернуть *с  лихвой* значит "с излишком, избытком".

Самым древним значением слова было "чрезмерно обильный, избыточный", как в игре "третий-лишний". Потом оно стало значить "плохой", "злой", "враждебный". В последнее время возникло новое значение - "до излишества удалой", "лихач".

(Лев Успенский)

---

И снова **[словарь Фасмера](http://vasmer.narod.ru/p368.htm)**:

> Слово: лишний.
>
> Ближайшая этимология: от лихой.
>
> Страницы: 2,507.

[Слово: **лихой**.](http://www.slovo.yaxy.ru/dic_et/p367.htm)

> Ближайшая этимология: лих, лихаґ, лиґхо, укр. лихиґй "злой, дурной,
> несчастный", др.-русск. лихъ "лишенный, печальный, злой, плохой,
> лихой, отважный", ст.-слав. лихъ ўllТtrioj (Супр., Клоц.), болг. лих,
> ж. лихаґ, ср. р. лихоґ "злобный, лихой, своенравный", сербохорв. ли?х,
> ли?хо, словен. li?h "нечетный, непарный", чеш. liґchyґ "лишний,
> нечетный, лукавый, пустой", польск. lichy "нечетный, плохой, бедный",
> в.-луж. lichi "голый, свободный", н.-луж. lichy "холостой". Дальнейшая
> этимология: Первонач. *leikso- от *loik-; ср. лек, отлек; родственно
> греч. le€yТqrix "потерявший волосы", le…yanon "остаток", далее лат.
> relinquЎ, -lictus "оставляю", греч. le…pw -- то же. Первонач. знач.
> было "остающийся, превышающий меру"; см. Бернекер 1, 718; Мейе, RS 4,
> 52 и сл. Разграничение слов liхъ "злой, дурной" и liхъ "лишний" не
> имеет оснований, вопреки Эндзелину (СБЭ 52, 198), Преобр. (I, 460 и
> сл.), Голубу (136); ср. Бернекер, там же; Ильинский, ИОРЯС 20, 3, 110
> и сл. Следует отклонить сравнение с лит. liґesas "худой", вопреки
> Эндзелину (там же), Буге (РФВ 67, 242), Маценауэру (LF 9, 204).

(К сожалению, в приведённой цитате искажены ударения и некоторые символы; без искажений цитата приводится в Викисловаре - первое, с чего я начала отвечать.)

Comment: Фасмер в Вики не писал, и это факт. В его этимологическом словаре, **данные которого использовались для составления этой неточной этимологии**, статьи *слишком* вообще нет.

Comment: @Aer Викисловарь ссылается на Фасмера. Это нормальная практика, цитировать по доступному источнику. Другое дело, если Вы заподозрили недостоверное цитирование, тогда ищите непосредственно у Фасмера, в словаре - и сравнивайте.

Comment: @behemothus я уже написал, что в словаре Фасмера нет такой этимологии **вообще**. Читайте комментарии, пожалуйста. А Викисловарь **часто** ссылается, при этом перевирая всё возможное и невозможное.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52071/discussion-on-answer-by-galina-avanesova---).

Answer (score 0):

Это собственно русское образование, возникшее на базе предложно-падежного сочетания предлога *с* и существительного *лишек* "избыток". Уже в русском языке XI—XVII вв. известно слово *сълишькомъ*, словарная фиксация — с 1731 г.

*Лишек* (древнерусское *лишекъ*) произошло вследствие присоединения суффикса *-ъкъ* к слову *лихъ* "лихой".

*(Используются сведения из "Этимологического словаря современного русского языка" А. К. Шапошникова и "Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН.)*

Подобная этимология приводится в "Большом универсальном словаре русского языка".

P. S. В ответе Галины Аванесовой говорится: "Фасмер уверен, что наречие "слишком" произошло от прилагательного "лишний", и ему пока никто не возразил". Макс Фасмер не был уверен (во всяком случае такое нигде не зафиксировано) в этом и этого не писал. Это дезинформация. Этимология составлена Александром Силоновым, причем, создавая ее, он сам придумал, что *слишком* произошло от *лишний* (этимологию прил. *лишний* же он взял в словаре Фасмера).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52074/discussion-on-answer-by-aer---).